# Qliksense background/text color on pivot table

Tags: colors, qliksense

I want to use pivot table to show minimum value by green color (text or background) in qliksense.

[image]

Comment: Maybe have a look at this post  https://community.qlik.com/message/1264348#1264348.  Its for QlikView but should work for QS.